# Почему выдает ошибку? SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

```
x = int(input())
h = x // 3600
m = (x // 60) % 60
a = m // 10
b = m % 10
s = x % 60
c = s // 10
d = s % 10
print(f'{h}:{a}{b}:{c}{d}')
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Указывает на ошибку в последней строке.

В чем проблема? Проверял в онлайн компиляторах, в 2 из 5 выдало ошибку.

Answer (score 4):

f-строки появились в Python начиная с версии 3.6. Некоторые онлайн-компиляторы могут использовать более старые версии Python. Вместо f-строк можно использовать метод `format` (пример будет работать на Python 2.7, Python 3.1 и новее):

```
x = int(input())
h = x // 3600
m = (x // 60) % 60
a = m // 10
b = m % 10
s = x % 60
c = s // 10
d = s % 10
print('{}:{}{}:{}{}'.format(h, a, b, c, d))
```

Comment: только, что установил Python 3.8.3 и попробовал через консоль: выдает ту же самую ошибку при использовании f-строк( ваш метод работает, но хотелось бы разобраться с этими f-строками

Comment: а вы уверены что в консоли у вас версия питона 3.8?

Comment: @Пельмень та же самая ошибка не может быть. Возможно скобка не закрыта или что-то еще.

Comment: тут тоже как-то странно: пишу Python выдает 2.7, пишу python3 выдает 3.8.3

Comment: @Пельмень, на linux (и скорее всего на mac тоже) команда python - это python2. Лучше вызывать как python3.8

Comment: А еслм интерпретатор один, то можно просто python3

Comment: спасибо, помогло!